# Reactjs redux store is not updating

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have an array of objects which contains `chosen:false`. What I'm doing is mapping this array of objects and when user clicks on it, it must change chosen to true.

This my current function:

```
 const selectCategories = (text) => {

  const updatedCategoriesArray = [...categoriesList].map((item) =>
    item.name === text ? {...item, chosen: !item.chosen} : item,
  );

  Promise.all(updatedCategoriesArray).then((data) => {
    dispatch(userActions.setSelectedCategories(data));
  });


 };
```

This actions sends updated array to the store and updates it correspondingly.

The problem is that Array is updating but I don't know why but redux store can not see it.

If I directly mutate object like this : `item.name === text ? item.chosen=!item.chosen : item`

It will work and I don't understand why,Any suggestions please?

Comment: There is no need for Promise.all, your `updatedCategoriesArray` is not an array of promises so it makes no sense. If this is not the **actual** code that behaves unexpectedly then I suspect you have a stale closure and could probably solve it with a thunk but without some of the actual code there is little to say about it.

Comment: So you mean it is better to use middleware rather than Promise.all

Comment: The Promise.all makes no sense, there is not one promise in the `updatedCategoriesArray`

Comment: Okay,Thank you I will try to solve it with middleware